# Responsive mode is not working in Joomla template made with Artisteer

Tags: css, templates, joomla, joomla2.5, responsive

I have a website with Joomla 2.5 CMS and template (theme) made with Artisteer 4.1.
Responsive (mobile) mode is not working, but template.responsive.css file is there and seems to be ok and general template structure seems to be ok too (in comparison to other templates which have no problems with responsive mode).
Under problem with responsive mode I mean that changing web site resolution make no changes which should be in this case.

How to fix responsive mode problem?

Comment: Joomla 2.5? Are you from the past? jk, I hope it's patched at least. You should really ask the template developer, at this point though such an old solution may be unsupported... otherwise you need to provide more detail: was it working? what did you do?

Answer (score 0):

Several things spring to mind:

1. Joomla 2.5 is very old and not supported any longer.
2. Since Joomla is old, it is very likely that the template that works with it does not proper support responsiveness.
3. Artisteer has never been known for it being responsive. Actually more that it does not work.

Solution is primarily to use another or more modern template (that you know is responsive). And better to first update to Joomla 3 (Joomla 4 is soon here).

If not, then you might have to make the template responsive your self - it only takes CSS skills and perhaps a Joomla module for a better module.